# Scripts - Find & Replace in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a JavaScript function pulling data from a webpage and placing the data in A,B,C,D of Google Sheets.
[Google Scripts Scraper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fn8mi.jpg)
I would like to use something that takes the value 'MKE' in column C, and replace it Milwaukee, WI  still leaving the address.

I ran across this script:

```
if (addressParts[1] == "MKE" || addressParts[1] === undefined) {
            addressParts[1] = "Milwaukee";
        } else if (addressParts[1] == "WMW") {
            addressParts[1] = "West Milwaukee";
        } else if (addressParts[1] == "WA") {
            addressParts[1] = "West Allis";
```

But am unaware if this script will work with my project.  Does anyone have any other suggestions for code to use?

Comment: Insert it where you need it... before your javascript function inserts the data from the webpage

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this code:

```
function getReplaced(value)
{

  var replacer = 
  {
    undefined: "Milwaukee",
    MKE: "Milwaukee",
    WMW: "West Milwaukee",
    WA: "West Allis"
  }
  var result = replacer[value]
  return result || value;
}

function TESTreplacer()
{

  Logger.log(getReplaced(undefined));        // Milwaukee
  Logger.log(getReplaced('MKE'));            // Milwaukee
  Logger.log(getReplaced('WMW'));            // West Milwaukee  
  Logger.log(getReplaced('WA'));             // West Allis
  Logger.log(getReplaced('Turtle Power'));   // Turtle Power

}
```

You may add new values into `replacer` or even make it separate object with it's own method `addValue`

Comment: I added this to my project, and it did not change any values.  I sent you an email regarding this, hopefully you can help out.

Comment: That is not an option: SO is a resourse for helping people, not doing their job. If you can't solve another part of code, you may accept this answer and post another question with the whole your original code.